# How to save time in the database in Go when using GORM and Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm currently parsing a time string and saving it to the db (Postgresql):

```
event.Time, _ := time.Parse("3:04 PM", "9:00 PM")
// value of event.Time now is: 0000-01-01 21:00:00 +0000 UTC
db.Create(&event)
```

It's giving me this error: `pq: R:"DateTimeParseError" S:"ERROR" C:"22008" M:"date/time field value out of range: \"0000-01-01T21:00:00Z\"" F:"datetime.c" L:"3540"`

`event.Time﻿⁠⁠⁠⁠`'s type is `time.Time`.

I also tried setting `event.Time`'s type to string and using time data type in postgresql:

```
type Event struct {
  Time string `gorm:"type:time
}
```

But now I'm getting an error when fetching records in the db:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 4: unsupported driver -> Scan pair: time.Time -> *string
```

Comment: That's because Go time.Time is actually a date. Currently I don't see a way to use PostgreSQL Time properly. If you aren't querying by it, I would suggest to use a simple string. Otherwise, store it as a full date.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I already tried to store it as a full date but it's giving me this error: `pq: R:"DateTimeParseError" S:"ERROR" C:"22008" M:"date/time field value out of range: \"0000-01-01T21:00:00Z\"" F:"datetime.c" L:"3540"`

Comment: As a workaround I'd suggest adding some dummy date like 2099-01-01 and you could then store your time and query on it properly having this in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Investigated this issue further. Currently, there's no support in GORM for any Date/Time types except `timestamp with time zone`

See this part of code from [dialect_postgres.go](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/dialect_postgres.go#L60):

```
case reflect.Struct:
   if _, ok := dataValue.Interface().(time.Time); ok {
      sqlType = "timestamp with time zone"
}
```

So basically I see two options for you:

Either use `varchar(10)` in DB, and `string` in Go, an simply save it as "9:00 PM" (where 10 is some number that suits you)

Or use `timestamp with time zone` in DB, `time.Time` in Go, and format your date part as a constant date, 01/01/1970, for example:

```
time.Parse("2006-01-02 3:04PM", "1970-01-01 9:00PM")
```

In that case you'll have to omit the date part in your presentation, but if you plan to select by date range, that could work better for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can set an arbitrary database-specific type with Gorm using `sql` tag

```golang
type Event struct {
  Time time.Time `sql:"type:timestamp without time zone"`
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me with gorm v1.23.5 and postgres 14.

Answer (score 0):

When updating the `DATETIME` field in SQL, the Go string must be in this format: `time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)`.

Answer (score 0):

From Postgres perspective the error stems from there being no year 0000. If you don't the date you may just be able to add 1 year to the converted timestamp giving '0001-01-01T21:00:00+00' which is a valid Postgres timestamp.

```
select '0000-01-01T21:00:00+00'::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC' 
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "0000-01-01T21:00:00+00"
```

Gives he same error. And just as a demonstration 1 day before 0001-01-01 gives:

```
select '0001-01-01T21:00:00+00'::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC' - interval '1 day' "day_before_1/1/1";
--day_before_1/1/1
--0001-12-31 21:00:00 BC
```