# Golang gorm time data type conversion

Tags: postgresql, go, time, go-gorm

**Situation:**

I'm using a *postgres* database and have the following struct:

```
type Building struct {
ID        int `json:"id,omitempty"`
Name      string `gorm:"size:255" json:"name,omitempty"`
Lon       string `gorm:"size:64" json:"lon,omitempty"`
Lat       string `gorm:"size:64" json:"lat,omitempty"`
StartTime time.Time `gorm:"type:time" json:"start_time,omitempty"`
EndTime   time.Time `gorm:"type:time" json:"end_time,omitempty"`
}
```

**Problem:**

However, when I try to insert this struct into the database, the following error occurs:

> parsing time ""10:00:00"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot
>   parse "0:00"" as "2006""}.

Probably, it doesn't recognize the `StartTime` and `EndTime` fields as *Time* type and uses *Timestamp* instead. How can I specify that these fields are of the type *Time*?

**Additional information**

The following code snippet shows my `Building` creation:

```
if err = db.Create(&building).Error; err != nil {
    return database.InsertResult{}, err
}
```

The SQL code of the Building table is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS building CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE building(
  id SERIAL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  lon VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL ,
  lat VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL ,
  start_time TIME NOT NULL ,
  end_time TIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Your code works in my environment and able to correctly insert data into database. From the error message, it seems that the error is happening when you ore creating `building`. can you paste the code?

Comment: @ymonad, can you check again?

Comment: I already tried setting the type of start_time and end_time for TIME, DATE, and TIMESTAMP, and all works, at least for `time.Now()`. here's the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5014d44ca999144ff06ffc05aa4acee3

Comment: So as @VonC mentions in the answer, you may update the gorm library to the newest one, or try VonC's answer.

Comment: @ymonad, I see, you use time.Now() which gives complete date and time, but I use a string like "10:00:00"

Comment: @RustamIbragimov were you able to find a fix/workaround for that? I'm just starting to look at how to handle mysql TIME.

Answer (score 8):

While gorm does not support the TIME type directly, you can always create your own type that implements the `sql.Scanner` and `driver.Valuer` interfaces to be able to put in and take out time values from the database.

Here's an example implementation which reuses/aliases `time.Time`, but doesn't use the day, month, year data:

```golang
const MyTimeFormat = "15:04:05"

type MyTime time.Time

func NewMyTime(hour, min, sec int) MyTime {
    t := time.Date(0, time.January, 1, hour, min, sec, 0, time.UTC)
    return MyTime(t)
}

func (t *MyTime) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case []byte:
        return t.UnmarshalText(string(v))
    case string:
        return t.UnmarshalText(v)
    case time.Time:
        *t = MyTime(v)
    case nil:
        *t = MyTime{}
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot sql.Scan() MyTime from: %#v", v)
    }
    return nil
}

func (t MyTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return driver.Value(time.Time(t).Format(MyTimeFormat)), nil
}

func (t *MyTime) UnmarshalText(value string) error {
    dd, err := time.Parse(MyTimeFormat, value)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *t = MyTime(dd)
    return nil
}

func (MyTime) GormDataType() string {
    return "TIME"
}
```

You can use it like:

```golang
type Building struct {
    ID        int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name      string `gorm:"size:255" json:"name,omitempty"`
    Lon       string `gorm:"size:64" json:"lon,omitempty"`
    Lat       string `gorm:"size:64" json:"lat,omitempty"`
    StartTime MyTime `json:"start_time,omitempty"`
    EndTime   MyTime `json:"end_time,omitempty"`
}

b := Building{
    Name:      "test",
    StartTime: NewMyTime(10, 23, 59),
}
```

For proper JSON support you'll need to add implementations for `json.Marshaler`/`json.Unmarshaler`, which is left as an exercise for the reader

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[How to save time in the database in Go when using GORM and Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519483/6309)"

> Currently, there's no support in GORM for any Date/Time types except [`timestamp with time zone`](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/6ff0c72557730b9055dd020d73781eb362f40f3a/dialect_postgres.go#L60-L61).

So you might need to parse a time as a date:

```
time.Parse("2006-01-02 3:04PM", "1970-01-01 9:00PM")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am have come across the same error. It seems like there is a mismatch between type of the column in the database and the Gorm Model

Probably the type of the column in the database is text which you might have set earlier and then changed the column type in gorm model.